# How do I create tables not "owned by sys" in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I tried to create a trigger:

```
create trigger afterupdate 
after insert on friends
for each row 


begin 
dbms_output.put_line('hello world');
end afterupdate;
```

However got the following error:

```
"cannot create triggers on objects owned by SYS"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the error, I am assuming that you are logging in to the database as `SYS` to create your tables and to write your code.  You do not want to use the `SYS` schema for that-- you should never create objects in the `SYS` schema.  You'll need to log in to the database as a different user.  In general, if you are building a brand new application, you would create a new user to own all the objects for the new application.

For example, if you're building a Facebook clone and you want to use the `USERS` tablespace for your data

```
CREATE USER facebook_appid
  IDENTIFIED BY <<password>>
  DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS
  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP;

GRANT CREATE SESSION,
      CREATE TABLE,
      CREATE TRIGGER
   TO facebook_appid;
```

You would then connect to the database as `facebook_appid` using the password you specified.

```
sqlplus facebook_appid/<<password>>@<<TNS alias>>
```

Once you've done that, you can create the table and the trigger.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is privilege issue . 
You are trying to create a trigger on table which is in SYS schema and you dont have privileges for doing so.

Please go to SYS schema and provide the user with privileges to create a trigger on the table.