# Can't create trigger in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I'm using Oracle 12c on my localhost. I wanted to create trigger for the tables.

It gives me an error:

`"ORA-04089: cannot create triggers on objects owned by SYS"`

I tried it  by creating another user and granted it to create a trigger as it mentioned in this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304174/how-do-i-create-tables-not-owned-by-sys-in-oracle) post.

But it gives me a same error.

Here is my USER's scritp that created

```
CREATE USER DEVELOPER
  IDENTIFIED BY <password>
  DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS
  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP
  PROFILE DEFAULT
  ACCOUNT UNLOCK;

-- 2 Roles for DEVELOPER 
GRANT CONNECT TO DEVELOPER CONTAINER=ALL;
GRANT RESOURCE TO DEVELOPER CONTAINER=ALL;
ALTER USER DEVELOPER DEFAULT ROLE NONE;

-- 3 System Privileges for DEVELOPER 
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO DEVELOPER;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO DEVELOPER;
GRANT CREATE TRIGGER TO DEVELOPER;

-- 2 Tablespace Quotas for DEVELOPER 
ALTER USER DEVELOPER QUOTA UNLIMITED ON SYSAUX;
ALTER USER DEVELOPER QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS;
```

Comment: did you follow all the steps exactly as mentioned in the post..?

Comment: @KaushikNayak, I updated my question, you could see my script for the user that I created

Comment: I couldn't see - connect developer; create trigger ...

Comment: You need to read this: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_04089_cannot_create_trigger.htm . Also, why would you need a trigger in the SYS schema? I mean, you better expose your original 
 problem here and what you got so far; then the users here might give you an even better solution.