# How to insert data into table which has a ref and scope

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-insert

This is my user defined Type which i have created.

```
create or Replace TYPE cust_address_typ_new AS OBJECT
    ( add_id NUMBER,   
    street_address     VARCHAR2(40)
    , postal_code        VARCHAR2(10)
    , city               VARCHAR2(30)
    , state_province     VARCHAR2(10)
    , country_id         CHAR(2)
    );
```

and the below is the table of new type

```
CREATE TABLE address_table OF cust_address_typ_new;
```

Now i created another table as below

```
CREATE TABLE customer_addresses (
   add_id NUMBER, 
   address REF cust_address_typ_new
   SCOPE IS address_table);
```

and now i'm trying to insert values into `customer_addresses`  table

```
insert into customer_addresses
values(1,SYSTEM.CUST_ADDRESS_TYP_NEW(1,'hi','87987','city','state',''))
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you storing the objects in `SYSTEM` schema?

Comment: @ Kaushik Nayak ,That is the default schema

Comment: And what is your problem? Does your code generate an error or is it something else. Please clarify your question.

Comment: There is no such thing as default schema for storing user data. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-CF1CD853-AF15-41EC-BC80-61918C73FDB5.htm#ADMQS12003 sys and system are meant for **administrative tasks** only. You are going to face a lot of issues if you dump  those  in SYS. You should have  a separate schema for the database user and create all your objects there. Also read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304174/how-do-i-create-tables-not-owned-by-sys-in-oracle

Comment: By the way, the `char` type is generally unhelpful and a source of obscure bugs. Do you want `'  '` (two blanks) to be inserted when you specify `''` (empty string)? Do you know which situations will invoke blank padding and which won't? It's best to use the standard `varchar2` for strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sqlcl (Oracle 12.1):

```
create or Replace TYPE cust_address_typ_new AS OBJECT ( 
  add_id NUMBER
, street_address VARCHAR2(40) 
, postal_code VARCHAR2(10) 
, city VARCHAR2(30) 
, state_province VARCHAR2(10) 
, country_id CHAR(2) 
);
/
-- Type CUST_ADDRESS_TYP_NEW compiled

CREATE TABLE address_table OF cust_address_typ_new ;
-- Table ADDRESS_TABLE created.

CREATE TABLE customer_addresses ( 
  add_id NUMBER
, address REF cust_address_typ_new SCOPE IS address_table
);
-- Table CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES created.
```

Errors

```
insert into customer_addresses 
values ( 1, SYSTEM.CUST_ADDRESS_TYP_NEW(1,'hi','87987','city','state','') ) ;

-- ORA-00904: "SYSTEM"."CUST_ADDRESS_TYP_NEW": invalid identifier

insert into customer_addresses 
values ( 1, CUST_ADDRESS_TYP_NEW( 1,'hi','87987','city','state','' ) ) ;

-- ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected REF ...CUST_ADDRESS_TYP_NEW got ...CUST_ADDRESS_TYP_NEW
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions127.htm):

> REF takes as its argument a correlation variable (table alias)
>   associated with a row of an object table or an object view. A REF
>   value is returned for the object instance that is bound to the
>   variable or row.

The following examples my help you:

```
-- {1} insert into the address_table ( 3 examples )

insert into address_table 
values (  1,'hi','87987','city','state','' ) ;

-- 1 row inserted.

insert into address_table
values( cust_address_typ_new( 2,'hi again','12345','city2','state2','' ) ) ;

-- 1 row inserted

insert into address_table
values( new cust_address_typ_new( 3,'hmpf','23456','city3','state3','' ) ) ;

-- 1 row inserted.

-- result
SQL> select * from address_table;
ADD_ID  STREET_ADDRESS  POSTAL_CODE  CITY   STATE_PROVINCE  COUNTRY_ID  
1       hi              87987        city   state           NULL        
2       hi again        12345        city2  state2          NULL        
3       hmpf            23456        city3  state3          NULL
```

Maybe you don't need the sequence (just added to fill the add_id column in the customer_addresses table).

```
-- {2} select from the address_table, use ref(), 
--     insert into customer_addresses

SQL> create sequence ca_seq start with 1000 increment by 1;
Sequence CA_SEQ created.

insert into customer_addresses
select ca_seq.nextval, ref(AT) from address_table AT ;

-- result
select * from customer_addresses;
    ADD_ID
----------
ADDRESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1000 
2202086FC2AC912CD41038E0530100007F525D6FC2AC912CCD1038E0530100007F525D                                                     

      1001 
2202086FC2AC912CD51038E0530100007F525D6FC2AC912CCD1038E0530100007F525D                                                     

      1002 
2202086FC2AC912CD61038E0530100007F525D6FC2AC912CCD1038E0530100007F525D
```